# Initramfs fails to mount sysroot for LVM volume

Tags: grub2, lvm, alpine-linux

I have a Dell 730xd with a PERC card that has two 32gb RAID1 disks exposed.  On the first I setup Alpine Linux using standard partitioning(boot, system, swap) with Grub.  This works perfectly fine.  I will refer to this as 'recovery' because this install is meant to be a recovery console for the system.

This system has this setup:

```
/dev/sda1 => /boot
/dev/sda2 => /root
/dev/sda3 => swap
```

Next I installed Alpine Linux on the second disk for my 'kube' system, it uses LVM so I can use snapshots to backup the system at runtime.  I then updated the /boot/grub/grub.cfg file on the '/dev/sda2' partition to contain the relevant parts from the new system, here are those sections:

```
insmod lvm

# omitted a lot of noise

menuentry 'Kube' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-lts-advanced-f6950bf5-5672-475a-a71e-3791696330eb' {
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd1,msdos1'
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 83f256b9-7313-4412-8d21-efc6772c09d8
        echo    'Loading Linux lts ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-lts root=/dev/mapper/vg0-lv_root ro modules=sd-mod,usb-storage,ext4 quiet rootfstype=ext4 rootdelay=15
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initramfs-lts
}

menuentry 'Recovery' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-lts-advanced-aadb875b-c5de-4c88-9da2-642a53ac270f' {
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1cd02d74-bf82-455d-9c71-e14f5717c386
        echo    'Loading Linux lts ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-lts root=UUID=aadb875b-c5de-4c88-9da2-642a53ac270f ro modules=sd-mod,usb-storage,ext4 quiet rootfstype=ext4
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initramfs-lts
}
```

The 'recovery' OS mounts the LVM volumes from the second system and from that OS I can see and modify the files fine.

The problem is that the second system fails to boot with this error:

```
mount: mounting /dev/vg0/lv_root on /sysroot failed: No such file or directory
Mounting root failed.
initramfs emergency recovery shell launched. Type 'exit' to continue boot
sh: can't access tty: job control turned off
```

If I run these commands:

```
lvm vgchange -ay
mount -t ext4 /dev/vg0/lv_root /sysroot
mount -t ext4 /dev/sda1 /sysroot/boot
exit
```

The system boots fine.

At this point I am completely confused on how to proceed.

Comment: What does it mean to update `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` on `/dev/sda2` if your `/boot` volume is `/dev/sda1`?

Comment: And you're using the kernel and initrd from the boot volume on your second drive (`hd1,msdos1`, which would likely be `/dev/sdb1`) to boot the second drive root, but then you `mount -t ext4 /dev/sda1 /sysroot/boot` on it (that's the one on the first drive, from the recovery installation)?  What you have mounted at `/boot` is not an immediate problem for booting, but then if you upgrade the kernel package now it's putting the kernel and the `initramfs` on the wrong `/boot`